# Disallow remote access to Tomcat Manager?

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7, tomcat-manager

According to the Tomcat7 docs, I can add a valve to prevent access to the Tomcat Manager app except from localhost:

```
<Context privileged="true">
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve"
        allow="127\.0\.0\.1"/>
</Context>
```

The docs are not so helpful in explaining where that snippet of XML is supposed to go.

Can someone help me with this, please?

Answer (score 3):

You modify `CATALINA_HOME/conf/Catalina/localhost/manager.xml` to add the filter to allow only local access (as in your post) or specific IPs

Add the `valve` within the `Context` tag of the `manager.xml`